# updating hubzilla repositories to newest version

Tags: repository, updating, hubzilla

I am hoping to find an answer to a question i have with hubzilla software. Does anyone know how to update the hubzilla repository to the latest version? Could you tell me a complete command to use in a terminal?

I tried looking on the hubzilla website for a command how to update the software but i could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

It depend somewhat on how you installed.

You should be in hubzillas root directory, ie. `/var/www/hubzilla`, or wherever you installed hubzilla.

The exact command to run is `./util/udall`. Make sure to do it as the user that owns the files, typically the user of the web server. On all systems I've used that would be www-data. In my case I would run this command:
`cd /var/www/hubzilla && sudo -u www-data ./util/udall`